# Remove installed ROS package

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed a ros package wih this command:

> $ sudo apt-get install
> ros-kinetic-novatel-gps-driver

Now I would like to remove this package and build it from its github page. What is the safest and cleanest way to do so?

I am aware of:

> $ sudo apt remove ros-kinetic-novatel-gps-driver

or

> $ sudo apt-get purge ros-kinetic-novatel-gps-driver

cheers,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339340/remove-installed-ros-package/) by [Farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25360/farid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 165 on 2019-12-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-06**:
This is not ROS-specific. `apt` (and `apt-get`) are tools provided by Debian (and Debian based Linux distributions such as Ubuntu).

`remove` and `purge` are exactly the two options you have to remove the Debian package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think there is no need to remove it. You can build it from your github page again and swtich which version you want to use by  running the command `source devel/setup.bash` in your ROS workspace.

Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [nofear123](https://answers.ros.org/users/39555/nofear123/) with karma: 16 on 2019-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0